# Excel Sheet Not Saving Data in Sheet 1

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-interop

I Excel File with 2 sheets, First sheet named as "PM" and second Sheet named as "km" when i try to enter data to sheet 1 from textboxes it successfully done but when i tried to enter data in sheet 2.. sheet 1 back to its original state(Empty)..
I checked the code i made at first 1 worksheet "xlsht" for both sheets but data not updated on both sheets then i made 2 functions with 2 worksheets but the problem is same, any idea why?

My Code:

```
protected void PM_Sheet1()
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Worksheet xlsht = new Worksheet();
            string path = @"D:\test.xlsx";
            xlsht = xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path).Worksheets["PM"];
            xlsht.Cells[11, 2] = UserNameTxt.Text + "@rasatop.com";
            xlsht.Cells[11, 4] = UserNameTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[14, 2] = SerialTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[16, 2] = WLANMacTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[16, 3] = LANMacTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[16, 4] = IPTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[14, 5] = ComputerTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[16, 5] = BarcodeTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[18, 5] = CPUTxt.Text.Substring(0, 26);
            xlsht.Cells[18, 4] = VGATxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[18, 3] = RAMTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[27, 4] = OSTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[5, 4] = System.DateTime.Today;
            xlsht.Cells[26, 4] = System.DateTime.Today;
            xlsht.Cells[9, 5] = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
            xlsht.SaveAs(@"D:\test1.xlsx");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Make Sure test.xlsx file in D:\ Drive");
        }
    }
    protected void PM_Sheet2()
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Worksheet xlsht = new Worksheet();
            string path = @"D:\test1.xlsx";
            xlsht = xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path).Worksheets["km"];
            xlsht.Cells[4, 2] = System.DateTime.Today;
            xlsht.Cells[6, 2] = UserNameTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[6, 4] = ComputerTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[6, 5] = BarcodeTxt.Text;
            xlsht.SaveAs(@"D:\" + ComputerTxt.Text + ".xlsx");
            xlApp.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured Cannot Save Sheet 2");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to `Save()` it after reopen the workbook?

Comment: couldn't find save() method but i found saveAs() method and i did it too but not executing project

Comment: @GBursali i edit the code in above check it

Comment: ok, you are using `xlsht.SaveAs(@"D:\" + ComputerTxt.Text + ".xlsx");` as the last save and you are checking that file, not `test1.xlsx` , right?

Comment: What is the value of `ComputerTxt.Text`?

Comment: on PM_Sheet1() i save the file as `test1.xlsx` but after that on PM_sheet2 i save the file as `xlsht.SaveAs(@"D:\" + ComputerTxt.Text + ".xlsx");`

Comment: @mjwills its getting computer name of the laptop.

Comment: when button pressed `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PM_Sheet1();
            PM_Sheet2();
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despite [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.saveas?view=excel-pia), `Worksheet.SaveAs()` would lead to an error, so you have to use `Workbook.SaveAs()`

You're also opening two different Excel instances where you need only one and apparently leaving both them running!

Finally, you'd better open an Excel instance for all operations and hence distributing necessary code at `Form` class level (declarations), `button1_Click()` level (`Excel` and `Workbook` initialization), helper methods (`Worksheet` initializations)

As follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Worksheet = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
using Workbook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook;
using MsExcelApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MsExcelApp xlApp =;
        Workbook xlWb;
        Worksheet xlSht;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"D:\test.xlsx";
            xlApp = new MsExcelApp();


            try
            {
                xlWb = xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            PM_Sheet1();
            PM_Sheet2();

            try
            {
                xlWb.SaveAs(@"D:\" + ComputerTxt.Text + ".xlsx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            xlApp.Quit();
        }




        protected void PM_Sheet1()
        {
            try
            {
                xlSht = xlWb.Worksheets["PM"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            xlSht.Cells[11, 2] = UserNameTxt.Text + "@rasatop.com";
            xlSht.Cells[11, 4] = UserNameTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[14, 2] = SerialTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[16, 2] = WLANMacTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[16, 3] = LANMacTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[16, 4] = IPTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[14, 5] = ComputerTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[16, 5] = BarcodeTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[18, 5] = CPUTxt.Text.Substring(0, 26);
            xlsht.Cells[18, 4] = VGATxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[18, 3] = RAMTxt.Text;
            xlsht.Cells[27, 4] = OSTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[5, 4] = System.DateTime.Today;
            xlSht.Cells[26, 4] = System.DateTime.Today;
            xlSht.Cells[9, 5] = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
        }

        protected void PM_Sheet2()
        {
           try
            {
                xlSht = xlWb.Worksheets["km"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            xlSht.Cells[4, 2] = System.DateTime.Today;
            xlSht.Cells[6, 2] = UserNameTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[6, 4] = ComputerTxt.Text;
            xlSht.Cells[6, 5] = BarcodeTxt.Text;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful and you correct many faults i did!